# SSRs parameters is empty report not running

Tags: sql, sql-server, reporting-services

I am using reportbuilder to build a report, using a subreport inside report.
For different dates I am some ad_site is empty, data from query is not coming.
data set query is

```
declare @count int

select count(distinct(computer_name)) as machine_count
  , ad_site as ad_site,ad_zone as ad_zone
from SCCM_PCrefreshdata
where ad_site is not null and snapshotdate like @startdate
group by ad_site,ad_zone
```

If I am entering date '2019-03-01' there is no data in table and same I am using ad_site for parameter in subreport

[image]

I HAVE kept parameter as allow nulls

[image]

Even after that if I run report and enter start date, for  which data is not existing it gives following error

[image]

Comment: `distinct` is not a function. Remove those redundant parentheses to make code clearer, i.e. `select count(distinct computer_name) as machine_count, ...`.

Comment: code is clear whether you remove distinct or not iam not getting data

Comment: `like @startdate`? I don't think this will return anything.

Comment: Whatever, I was giving you an advice on how to write code that _you_ and whoever reads it understand...

Comment: @startdate is parameter i have posted snapshot for this particular start date its doesnt have date in sccm refresh table so ad_site is empty. ad_site is used parameters and it takes  data from dataset query how to handle when dataset return no rows.

Comment: You might need to map your main report parameter to the subreport parameter...

Comment: If you wish to keep parameter to allow nulls then your dataset query should also reference this concept, ie: where ad_site is null and snapshotdate like @startdate

Comment: I think john has the right idea.  The parameter properties need to match on the subreport and the subreport properties in the main report.

Answer (score 0):

If you wish to keep parameter to allow nulls then your dataset query should also reference this concept, ie: where ad_site is null and snapshotdate like @startdate